# .htaccess mod_rewrite redirect subdomain to url, with preserving subdomain in url path

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I made simple web page at http://www.domain.com/mobile/{rest of url}

and i want to have http://mobile.domain.com/{rest of url}

On other forums, ppl tolde me to move page, unfortunately it's not possible since that page is using other controllers and models from the rest of page and /mobile/ is not folder, it's name of codeigniter controller that is also defined buy some other htaccess rules

I created subdomain mobile dot domain.com and i want to redirect all traffic from it WITH keeping URL in this form: mobile dot domain dot com/{path}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this to your htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mobile.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobile/$1  [L]
```

If you have other rewrite rules in your htaccess file you may want to add this before the other rules.